# How can I check if a substring contains parentheses, and if so, remove the entire substring in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

Getting input from a JTextPane. My code thus far just isolates the substring. Is there a method in Java that I can use to remove it?

For example, this string here:

There are seven(7) words in this string.

Would produce this string:

There are words in this string.

```
public void insertString (int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(offset, str, a);

        String text = getText(0, getLength());
        int before = findLastNonWordChar(text, offset);
        if (before < 0) 
            before = 0;
        int after = findFirstNonWordChar(text, offset + str.length());
        int wordL = before;
        int wordR = before;

        while(wordR <= after) {
            if(wordR == after || String.valueOf(text.charAt(wordR)).matches("\\W")) {
                if(text.substring(wordL, wordR).contains("(\\W)*(())")){
                     //do something here to remove substring
                }
                wordL = wordR;
            }
            wordR++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove anything between a pair of () ? Can there be a few pair ? Can the input include only 9 or only ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can use string replace method to remove that substring.

```
if(text.substring(wordL, wordR).contains("(\\W)*(())")){
                     //do something here to remove substring
                  String newText = text.replace(text.substring(wordL, wordR), "");
                }
```